# Unable to find ScyllaDb tarball and rpm downloadable link

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I require to upgrade scyllaDB on RHEL based system. tried to find rpm or terball of scyllaDB but unable to find and download. many times I visited scyllaDB official site where I found the link for binary/RPM but not successful to download. Please provide downloadable link of all scylladb version RPM or tarball.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Asking download links here is totally off-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scylla does not provide a tarrball download yet.
RPM download, from repo is available here https://www.scylladb.com/download/centos_rpm/ (registration required)

You can also compile from code from the source code https://github.com/scylladb/scylla

Tzach
(Scylla Product Manager)

Answer (score 0):

In https://www.scylladb.com/ you press "Downloads", and there "Scylla Open Source - get started". There, since you wanted to get a binary (not sources or AMI for AWS etc.), you press the "Binary" tab. There you can get binaries for several distros including "RHEL 7" which I guess you want.

BUT, at that point you need to register with a valid email to receive the actual instructions for downloading the RPMs. Since you don't see these instructions first, it's a bit of a mystery what will these instructions contain, but it turns out, these are real instructions on how to fetch the RPMs you need and how to install and run it ;-)